# Using FileChooser to save a writableimage image

Tags: image, javafx, filechooser

I have a writableimage and I want to save by using a FileChooser.
How would I do this, as it doesn't work with this code:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

          //Set extension filter
          FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.png)", "*.png");
          fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

          //Show save file dialog
          File file = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(primaryStage);

          if(file != null){
              SaveFile(writableImage, file);
          }
      }
```

Here is the code for the SaveFile() Class:

```
private void SaveFile(writableimage content, File file){
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;

        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        fileWriter.write(content);
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a file writer you would need an AWT buffered image reader, try this

```
private void SaveFile(Image content, File file){
    try {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I also found this online http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2014/12/javafx-filechooser-open-and-save-image.html

Edit: You should also print your exception because when it breaks and you don't know why it will tell what line broke it